# Can a member function of a superclass access a member function of a subclass? And how?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Pretty sure this is an easy question, but I've just come over from the Ruby world where everything is unicorns and rainbows, and I need a serious reality adjustment.  (I also suspect the title of this question is incorrectly worded, but I don't know the C++ terminology (yet) for what I'm asking.)

#### the question

In the following code, how can I get `B::complex_method_on_x()` use the value returned by `B::x()`?  As it is, it is using the value returned by `A::x()`.  (The `printf()`s should make it obvious what I'm expecting.)

#### the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
public:
  int x() { return 42; }
  int complex_method_on_x() { return 2 * x(); }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  int x() { return 1; };
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B b;
  printf("a.x() = %d (expect 42)\n", a.x());
  printf("a.complex_method_on_x() = %d (expect 84)\n", a.complex_method_on_x());
  printf("b.x() = %d (expect 1)\n", b.x());
  printf("b.complex_method_on_x() = %d (expect 2)\n", b.complex_method_on_x());
  return 0;
}
```

Running it, I get:

```
$ ./test_subclass
a.x() = 42 (expect 42)
a.complex_method_on_x() = 84 (expect 84)
b.x() = 1 (expect 1)
b.complex_method_on_x() = 84 (expect 2)
```

Specifically, in class `B`, I don't want to re-type the definition of `complex_method_on_x()`; I want to inherit that from the superclass.  But I want `complex_method_on_x()` to call `B`'s definition of `x()`; as it is, it is calling `A`'s definition of `x()`.

I don't want to make `x()` virtual, because then every subclass of `A` would have to define `x()`; I'd like to use the A's definition of `x()` if the subclass doesn't provide it.

Comment: "because then every subclass of A would have to define x()" - not the case.

Comment: don't confuse virtual and pure virtual.

Comment: Q.E.D.  Thanks -- Boo's answer makes it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
public:
  virtual int x() { return 42; }
  int complex_method_on_x() { return 2 * x(); }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  int x() { return 1; };
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B b;
  printf("a.x() = %d (expect 42)\n", a.x());
  printf("a.complex_method_on_x() = %d (expect 84)\n", a.complex_method_on_x());
  printf("b.x() = %d (expect 1)\n", b.x());
  printf("b.complex_method_on_x() = %d (expect 2)\n", b.complex_method_on_x());
  return 0;
}
```

add virtual on A::x()

Comment: Ah!!  What I did not previously know was that a virtual member function could include a default implementation.  Got it!  Thanks.

Comment: Grab a C++ and read up on C++ inheritance, it will save you time in the long run :)

Comment: Your answer is almost perfect(+1): Just change the last line to `A::x()`

Comment: good advice but also, practice a lot : for me at least inheritance was not very clear at the begining. @ alain true, My caps is sometimes hard to press

Comment: @dutt - just you wait.  In two weeks I'll be able to explain the precedence and order of initializers and object slicing.  ;) Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 0):

A superclass can access a subclass methods using virtual reserved keyword to declare an [abstract functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/71019/).

```
class baseClass {
  public:
  baseClass(){
    PrintClassName();
  }

  virtual void GetClassName()=0;
};

class subClass : public baseClass {
  public:
  virtual void GetClassName(){cout<<"buttonClass";}
};
```

Applied to your case:

```
class A {
public:
   int complex_method_on_x() { return 2 * subclass_x(); }
   virtual void subclass_x()=0;
};

class B:public A{
   virtual void subclass_x(){return 1}
};
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure how this would work with C++, not knowing the language specifics myself, but I would think changing your code to be something along the lines of

```
int complex_method_on_x() { return 2 * self.x(); }
```

would do the trick.  Basically, force the x() inside the complex_method_on_x() to refer to the calling class' definition of x(), rather than the locally scoped definition.

Comment: Why on earth would you post a wild guess about a language you don't know?

Comment: Because at the time there were no other answers, and from a theoretical OOP standpoint it's not a BAD guess.  Like, how is that wild?  Seems totally reasonable.

Comment: This is clearly going to quickly devolve into a mudslinging competition, so I'll leave off with this: a educated guess is not inherently bad just because it is wrong.  My guess was on point for other languages, and MIGHT have been right for C++.

Comment: @NickCoelius: fwiw, I'd already tried { return 2 * this->x(); } which is syntactically correct, but no joy.

Comment: Guessing is no good in a programming language IMHO. This is how you introduce Undefined Behaviour and other nasty bugs that don't always show up in testing and are hard to spot in the code.

Comment: @dyp That makes no sense.  GUESSING at a solution is utterly different from HACKING a solution that you don't necessarily know how it works (if it does).  My answer, had it worked, is clearly explainable and would make sense, avoiding this nominal "Undefined Behavior".  It was absolutely an educated guess.

Comment: Guessing a solution means you try something and test if it works. Undefined Behaviour is something that you either can't test for or that is very hard to test for. Guessing means that you have no experience with a solution and that you don't know how it's specified ("how it works").

Comment: @NickCoelius: I have respect for relative newcomers who dip their toes into the world of Stack Overflow.  In this case, I side with Oli and dyp for the simple reason that people consult Stack Overflow for expert answers.  Guesses, even educated guesses, dilute the value of Stack Overflow as a resource (especially if those educated guesses are wrong).  In this land, it's better to hold your tongue if you don't know the answer.  (I guess the downvotes make that pretty obvious by now, ouch...)